# querySelector() only giving one class instead of multiple

Tags: javascript, queryselector

In my code I am trying to get all classes which begin with priceList_ into an array for later use. the code I used to do that is: `var prefix = document.querySelector('[class^="priceList_"]').className;`
There is one problem I am having with this code, which is that it only gives the first class with that prefix instead of giving an array of classes. Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: Did u try ```querySelectorAll()```?

Comment: `.querySelector()` does not return "classes". It returns the first element that matches a given selector. Why do you want the classes in the first place? That seems... strange...

Comment: @abellay thank you for the answer, I just tried out that code, but it returns an undefined value

Comment: Its undefined because its a NodeList not a single item. To get the className you need to use a loop or access elements via their index

Comment: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll()`, it gives `NodeList`. It is iterable.

Comment: thank you, I just tried it and someone told me to remove the .className which comes after, which made it work now without giving me undefined back

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using `document.querySelectorAll`, `document.querySelector` purpose is to find the first element on the page matching the condition.

Just to add

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="priceList_"]').className
```

will error as the returned object is an NodeList of Nodes, not a singular Node (from which you'd be able to get the classe's).

If you wanted to obtain a structured array of each elements classe's then do the below

```
const classes = [...document.querySelectorAll('[class^="priceList_"]')].map(elem => elem.className);
```

This will assign an array of classe's (in the order of the DOM elements on the page). You could also do

```
const classes = [];

for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll('[class^="priceList_"]')) {

    classes.push(elem.className);
}

console.log('CLASSES', classes);
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector()` returns the first result, if you want multiple results use `querySelectorAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Element.classList` instead of `className`. You can also call `classList.entries()` to get an iterator.

You can also get an array from `className` with `Element.className.split(" ")`

[classList on MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)